# "Source image not resolvable" LiipImagineBundle

Tags: php, symfony

Liip imagine Bundle does not create cached folders for one of the imagine filters.

```
liip_imagine:
  resolvers:
   default:
      web_path: ~

driver: imagick

filter_sets:
    cache: ~
    gallery_image:
        quality: 75
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [1600, 1000], mode: inset }
    product_unit:
        quality: 75
        filters:
            upscale: { min: [1200, 400] }
            thumbnail: { size: [1200, 400], mode: outbound }
    graph:
        quality: 75
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [1200, 630], mode: inset }
            background: { size: [1200, 630], color: '#F29400' }
            thumbnail: { size: [1200, 630], mode: inset }
    app_logo:
        quality: 75
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [200, 80], mode: inset }
            background: { size: [200, 80], color: '#fff' }
            thumbnail: { size: [200, 80], mode: inset }
    shop_logo:
        quality: 75
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [150, 60], mode: inset }
            background: { size: [150, 60], color: '#fff' }
            thumbnail: { size: [150, 60], mode: inset }
```

It does not create "shop_logo". But it does create other cache images [graph, gallery_image,app_logo etc]♣

I tried with

```
php app/console liip:imagine:cache:resolve app/Resources/images/shops/shop.jpg --filters=shop_logo
```

I get Error

> [Liip\ImagineBundle\Exception\Binary\Loader\NotLoadableException]
>     Source image not resolvable "app/Resources/images/shops/shop.jpg"

and When I access the image with the url i have 404 error.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/cache/resolve/shop_logo/shop.jpg
```

and I do have 0775 permission for media I also tried with 777.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem with LiipImagineBundle 1.7 I downgraded to 1.6 and it works fine.

See : [git hub Issue](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/issues/849)